# Casting DbContext in UnitOfWork in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been searching for the Repository and Unit of Work Pattern in C#, and so far this is what I found:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T:class
{
    private DbContext context;
    private DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

However, in a project that was given to me for study, I saw this one:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T:class
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork
    private readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public Repository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork
        _dbSet = ((DbContext)_unitOfWork).Set<T>();
    }
}
```

Can someone please clarify the difference for me? Any explanation will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No much diference technically, but the use of the interface is much better, because you can abstract the `DbContext`, look if you need to change the EF to another ORM, you will just need to implement an concrete UnitOfWork, so the change will be less traumatic.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. :)

Comment: ````Entry```` method is from **DbContext** not **DbSet**, try this ````((DbContext)_unitOfWork).Entry(entity)```` @Cyval